# Clock issue in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ntp

I could see that my clock does not work right. For example, now it's 15:49, and  Ubuntu has 16:10.

It takes the time from Internet and I don't know why change it when it wants.

`/etc/default/ntp` it only has `NTPD_OPTS='-g'`

I don't know what file I have to see or change.

Comment: What does "ntpq -c pe" show?

Comment: Both offset and jitter are very high - what type of Internet connection do you have and is it stable?

Comment: I have optical fiber 100/10

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/26940/62688

Comment: At the momento works fine with your response @Martin Schröder. I'm going to confirm it when I restart the pc. Thanks

Comment: It does not work :( !! It has an hour late and it only works when I restart the pc, then, after a few minutes, does not work properly